# How to split one row two datetime columns to mutiple rows and group by date

Tags: sql, oracle

#### Sample Data

If here's a data like :

```sql
ID,EQP,PREVIOUSTIME,TRANSACTIONTIME,OLDSTATE,NEWSTATE
1,HT-001,2020/01/01 12:00:00,2020/01/01 13:00:00,IDLE,RUN
2,HT-001,2020/01/01 13:00:00,2020/01/05 15:00:00,RUN,IDLE
3,HT-001,2020/01/05 15:00:00,2020/01/05 16:00:00,IDLE,RUN
4,HT-001,2020/01/05 16:00:00,2020/01/05 18:00:00,RUN,IDLE

5,HT-002,2020/01/01 12:00:00,2020/01/01 13:00:00,IDLE,RUN
6,HT-002,2020/01/01 13:00:00,2020/01/05 15:00:00,RUN,IDLE
7,HT-002,2020/01/05 15:00:00,2020/01/05 16:00:00,IDLE,RUN
8,HT-002,2020/01/05 16:00:00,2020/01/05 18:00:00,RUN,IDLE
```

#### What I expect

query `select * from SomeView` or `select * from SomeFunction(datetime_of_now)` or store pocedure
to get below result (datetime of now is 2020/01/06 12:00:00)

```
Date        ,EQP    ,STATE  ,COST_TIME(Hour)
2020/01/01  ,HT-001 ,IDLE   ,1
2020/01/01  ,HT-001 ,RUN    ,11
2020/01/02  ,HT-001 ,RUN    ,24
2020/01/03  ,HT-001 ,RUN    ,24
2020/01/04  ,HT-001 ,RUN    ,24
2020/01/05  ,HT-001 ,IDLE   ,7 (1+6)
2020/01/05  ,HT-001 ,RUN    ,2 (2+15)
2020/01/06  ,HT-001 ,IDLE   ,12

2020/01/01  ,HT-002 ,IDLE   ,1
2020/01/01  ,HT-002 ,RUN    ,11
2020/01/02  ,HT-002 ,RUN    ,24
2020/01/03  ,HT-002 ,RUN    ,24
2020/01/04  ,HT-002 ,RUN    ,24
2020/01/05  ,HT-002 ,IDLE   ,7 (1+6)
2020/01/05  ,HT-002 ,RUN    ,2 (2+15)
2020/01/06  ,HT-002 ,IDLE   ,12
```

#### Test Demo Link

[Oracle 11g Release 2 | db<>fiddle](https://dbfiddle.uk/?rdbms=oracle_11.2&fiddle=d3aae9392996060875e47640f0a7bc29)

#### What I have tried to meet with difficulties

- i have no idea to split over one day to mutiple date rows.
  e.g : split one row previoustime~transactiontime is 01/01 ~ 01/05 to aleast 5 rows
- split the last one to datetime of now

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Use a recursive sub-query factoring clause to generate the day boundaries and  calculate durations then aggregate:

**Oracle Setup**:

```sql
CREATE TABLE table1 ( ID,EQP,PREVIOUSTIME,TRANSACTIONTIME,OLDSTATE,NEWSTATE ) AS
SELECT 1,'HT-001',DATE '2020-01-01' + INTERVAL '12:00:00' HOUR TO SECOND,DATE '2020-01-01' + INTERVAL '13:00:00' HOUR TO SECOND,'IDLE','RUN' FROM DUAL UNION ALL
SELECT 2,'HT-001',DATE '2020-01-01' + INTERVAL '13:00:00' HOUR TO SECOND,DATE '2020-01-05' + INTERVAL '15:00:00' HOUR TO SECOND,'RUN','IDLE' FROM DUAL UNION ALL
SELECT 3,'HT-001',DATE '2020-01-05' + INTERVAL '15:00:00' HOUR TO SECOND,DATE '2020-01-05' + INTERVAL '16:00:00' HOUR TO SECOND,'IDLE','RUN' FROM DUAL UNION ALL
SELECT 4,'HT-001',DATE '2020-01-05' + INTERVAL '16:00:00' HOUR TO SECOND,DATE '2020-01-05' + INTERVAL '18:00:00' HOUR TO SECOND,'RUN','IDLE' FROM DUAL UNION ALL
SELECT 5,'HT-002',DATE '2020-01-01' + INTERVAL '12:00:00' HOUR TO SECOND,DATE '2020-01-01' + INTERVAL '13:00:00' HOUR TO SECOND,'IDLE','RUN' FROM DUAL UNION ALL
SELECT 6,'HT-002',DATE '2020-01-01' + INTERVAL '13:00:00' HOUR TO SECOND,DATE '2020-01-05' + INTERVAL '15:00:00' HOUR TO SECOND,'RUN','IDLE' FROM DUAL UNION ALL
SELECT 7,'HT-002',DATE '2020-01-05' + INTERVAL '15:00:00' HOUR TO SECOND,DATE '2020-01-05' + INTERVAL '16:00:00' HOUR TO SECOND,'IDLE','RUN' FROM DUAL UNION ALL
SELECT 8,'HT-002',DATE '2020-01-05' + INTERVAL '16:00:00' HOUR TO SECOND,DATE '2020-01-05' + INTERVAL '18:00:00' HOUR TO SECOND,'RUN','IDLE' FROM DUAL UNION ALL
SELECT 9,'HT-002',DATE '2020-01-05' + INTERVAL '18:00:00' HOUR TO SECOND,DATE '2020-01-06' + INTERVAL '00:00:00' HOUR TO SECOND,'IDLE','IDLE' FROM DUAL;
```

**Query**:

```sql
WITH days ( eqp, dt, state, next_dt, max_dt ) AS (
  SELECT eqp,
         previoustime,
         oldstate,
         LEAST( TRUNC( previoustime ) + 1, transactiontime ),
         transactiontime
  FROM   (
    SELECT eqp,
           previoustime,
           transactiontime,
           oldstate,
           newstate
    FROM   table1
    UNION ALL
    SELECT eqp,
           MAX( transactiontime ),
           TRUNC( MAX( transactiontime ) + INTERVAL '23:59:59' HOUR TO SECOND ),
           MAX( newstate ) KEEP ( DENSE_RANK LAST ORDER BY transactiontime ),
           NULL
    FROM   table1
    GROUP BY eqp
  )
UNION ALL
  SELECT eqp,
         next_dt,
         state,
         LEAST( next_dt + 1, max_dt ),
         max_dt
  FROM   days
  WHERE  next_dt < max_dt
)
SELECT TRUNC( dt ) AS dt,
       eqp,
       state,
       SUM( ROUND( ( next_dt - dt ) * 24 ) ) AS cost_time
FROM   days
GROUP BY eqp, TRUNC( dt ), state
HAVING SUM( ROUND( ( next_dt - dt ) * 24 ) ) > 0
ORDER BY eqp, dt, state;
```

**Output**:

> ```
> DT                  | EQP    | STATE | COST_TIME
> :------------------ | :----- | :---- | --------:
> 2020-01-01 00:00:00 | HT-001 | IDLE  |         1
> 2020-01-01 00:00:00 | HT-001 | RUN   |        11
> 2020-01-02 00:00:00 | HT-001 | RUN   |        24
> 2020-01-03 00:00:00 | HT-001 | RUN   |        24
> 2020-01-04 00:00:00 | HT-001 | RUN   |        24
> 2020-01-05 00:00:00 | HT-001 | IDLE  |         7
> 2020-01-05 00:00:00 | HT-001 | RUN   |        17
> 2020-01-01 00:00:00 | HT-002 | IDLE  |         1
> 2020-01-01 00:00:00 | HT-002 | RUN   |        11
> 2020-01-02 00:00:00 | HT-002 | RUN   |        24
> 2020-01-03 00:00:00 | HT-002 | RUN   |        24
> 2020-01-04 00:00:00 | HT-002 | RUN   |        24
> 2020-01-05 00:00:00 | HT-002 | IDLE  |         7
> 2020-01-05 00:00:00 | HT-002 | RUN   |        17
> ```

*db<>fiddle [here](https://dbfiddle.uk/?rdbms=oracle_18&fiddle=1948eb32c86425491927af2f07357ef5)*

Comment: @Wei Updated with a much simpler query.

Comment: Wouldn't it be cleaner to move the calculations out of the cte, leaving the cte to just expand the rows to one per day? Rather than repeating least, trunc, etc, calculations?

Comment: @Wei Updated again to fix the last row per group.